# this and lexical scope

Tags: javascript

At [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), Mozilla explains what 'this' references in the following way:

> In general, the object bound to `this` in the current scope is
>   determined by how the current function was called, it can't be set by
>   assignment during execution, and it can be different each time the
>   function is called.

Under normal circumstances, I understand `this` and how its reference changes.

The book Pro JavaScript Design Patterns says the following about lexical scope

> JavaScript is also lexically scoped, which means that functions run in
>   the scope in which they are defined, not the scope they are executed
>   in.

So 'this' depends on how the current function was called, while lexical scope means functions are run in the scope in which they are defined.

My question is, can `this` ever be part of the lexical scope, and, if so, how do I understand the fact that this depends on how the current function was called, while lexical scope restricts functions to the scope in which they are defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just think of them as separate concerns.

- The variable scope of a function will never change.
- The value of `this` *will* change depending on how the function is invoked. Given the same function, different invocations give the same function a different `this`.

  ```
  var foo = (function() {
                var bar = "bar";
                return function() { console.log(bar, this); };
            })();

  foo();    // the default `this`

  var someObj = {some: "object"};
  foo.call(someObj);    // `this` is someObj

  var aDiffObj = {aDiff: "object"};
  foo.apply(aDiffObj);  // `this` is aDiffObj

  var anotherObj = {another: "object", foo:foo}; 
  anotherObj.foo();     // `this` is anotherObj

  var binderObj = {binder: "object"};
  var bound = foo.bind(binderObj);
  bound();              // `this` is binderObj

  new foo(); // `this` is a new object being constructed, 
             //      which has the prototype of `foo` in its prototype chain
  ```

  All the invocations have access to the `bar` variable, but a different `this` value.

So given the current function syntax in ECMAScript, `this` will never be taken from the lexical scope, but will always be assigned a value based on the invocation.

There's a new function syntax in the works that will likely have a lexical `this`, but that's sometime in the future.

Comment: Don't forget `bind`! (although a little different)

Comment: @Ian: Ah yes, forgot that one. I'll update. ...@@acjohnson55 and `new` too.

Comment: @acjohnson55 Haha text copier!

Comment: @Ian It was a clean room reimplementation of your text :)

Comment: +1, but I would go further than " think of them as separate concerns", scope and this are entirely different concepts.

Comment: @acjohnson55 Yeah yeah yeah :)

Answer (score 2):

The ES6 arrow function declaration syntax changes Javascript's 'this' binding rules so that 'this' always refers to the lexical context rather than changing depending upon how the function is called.

This defines lexical scope for 'this'...

```
var myFunc = () => {
  // function contents here
}
```

The arrow function declaration syntax above redefines 'this' binding to a 'lexical this.'  Be careful though, there are good reasons not to confuse the issue by using 'this' in such a way that there are two different sets of binding rules within your code. If you can avoid it by making peace with .bind(this) you're probably in better shape.